# Getting warning about non-portability when trying to install GNU GO on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, make, gnu

I'm trying to install GNU GO on Ubuntu OS, but it is not working.

https://www.gnu.org/software/gnugo/download.html

I've downloaded the tar.gz source code, then:

1. unzipped using  the `gzip` followed by the `tar` command
2. configured using `./configure`
3. tried to install using the command `make`, but installation fails. I get the warning `warning: the use of defined may not be portable.`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: gnugo package is already available in Ubuntu. You can install it with `sudo apt install gnugo` command. Just to make sure, do you really want to compile it from source code?

Comment: installation worked using `sudo apt install gnugo` !

Comment: thank you very much, @Biswapriyo! I was trying to install using `sudo apt-get install gnugo`, but it was not working! Can you tell me why?

Comment: I am not sure about it but `apt-get` and `apt` both works in my system.